# how can I get external files in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get images with Xamarin forms Android and I don't know how to do it.

I have a list called listNameImg (I have the name of the each image there). So, what i want is search each image and then save it in a MultipartFormDataContent

This is my code:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content3 = new MultipartFormDataContent();

private async void takePhotos()
    {
        try
        {

            var file2 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true
            });

            while (file2 != null)
            {
                Image im = new Image();
                im.ClassId = contador.ToString();
                im.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file2.Path);
                im.HeightRequest = 600;
                im.WidthRequest = 600;
                im.MinimumHeightRequest = 600;
                im.MinimumWidthRequest = 600;
                im.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                im.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                im.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;


                imgs.Children.Add(im);

                Button deleteButton = new Button();
                deleteButton.ClassId = contador.ToString();
                deleteButton.Text = "Borrar imagen";
                deleteButton.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
                deleteButton.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                deleteButton.MinimumWidthRequest = 100;
                deleteButton.ClassId = contador.ToString();
                deleteButton.AutomationId = contador.ToString();
                deleteButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) => {
                    listDelete.Add(Convert.ToInt32(deleteButton.ClassId));
                    imgs.Children.Remove(im);
                    imgs.Children.Remove(deleteButton);
                };
                imgs.Children.Add(deleteButton);
                
                listImgName.Add(file2.OriginalFilename);

                file2 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = true
                });

                contador++;
            }

            btnScannerQR.IsVisible = false;
            btnSacarFotos.IsVisible = true;
            btnEnviarImagenes.IsVisible = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Sorry we had a problem. Try again.", "OK");
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
        }

private async void storageNameInList() {
string testPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "listNameImg.txt");
                
                if (File.Exists(testPath) == false)
                {
                    File.Create(testPath);
                }
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(testPath);

                foreach (var s in listImgName)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(s);
                }
                tw.Close();
}
```

what I'm trying:

```
private async void sendImages(){
string testPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "listNameImg.txt");

var imgGroup = Directory.GetFiles(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
                TextReader tw = new StreamReader(testPath);
                String line;

                int cont = 0;

                while ((line = tw.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
                    content3.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(line)), "file", line);
                    cont++;


                }
```

}

My problems are:

1. how can I write in the file .txt correctly?
2. how can I get the images and save it in the MultipartFormDataContent?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you saving just the img file name and not the full path?

Comment: A multipart file is MIME which is the body of an HTTP message.  The multipart data starts with two dashes at the beginning of a line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Jason I get this "content://media/external/images/media/IMG_20220818_111337.jpg" for example. but I can't reach the image with this... or can I?

Comment: That’s an Android ContentUrl